# Yandex авторизация

Tags: php, curl

Авторизация проходит на почте, но идет безконечный цикл обновления, там нужен в GET параметр `uid=****`. Как его получить?

```
$cookie_box = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'; 
$login = '****';
$password = '***';
$common_yandex = curl_init('https://passport.yandex.ru/passport?mode=auth&amp;msg=money'); 

curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"login=$login&passwd=$password"); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_box); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
$html = curl_exec($common_yandex); 

curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mail.yandex.ru/neo2/?dpda=yes&uid=1743813725&login=fixgame2#inbox");
$html = curl_exec($common_yandex);

echo $html;

curl_close($common_yandex);
```

Comment: приведите ваш скрипт в качестве исходных данных

Comment: С помощью чего вы пытаетесь авторизоваться? Пока не нашел требований uid в документации: https://tech.yandex.ru/oauth/doc/dg/reference/console-client-docpage/#get-code

Comment: Для начала пара вопросов: 1. Почему в URL `&amp;`? 2. Почему `$login` и `$password` не экранируются?

Comment: Авторизация проходит, но не открывает почту, Если зайти на почту то ссылка вот такая "mail.yandex.ru/neo2/?uid=196234269&login=looper94#inbox" Если через curl Тогда вот так mail.yandex.ru/neo2/?no-chache=558

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решил другим методом вытаскивать все контакты с почты, выведет файл в cvs формате,  вот код:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$cookie_box = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'; 
$login = '';
$password = '';
$common_yandex = curl_init('https://passport.yandex.ru/passport?mode=auth&amp;msg=money'); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"login=$login&passwd=$password"); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_box); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
$html = curl_exec($common_yandex); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_POST, 0); 
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mail.yandex.ru/neo2/handlers/handlers3.jsx?_h=settings-color-schemes-text,folders,labels,messages,service-emails,second-level-zones");
$html = curl_exec($common_yandex);
$uid_and_login = json_decode($html);
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($common_yandex, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mail.yandex.ru/neo2/handlers/abook-epxort.jsx?_uid=".$uid_and_login->uid."&tp=4&lang=ru");
$html = curl_exec($common_yandex);
curl_close($common_yandex); 
echo $html;
?>
```